# Compute the confidence interval of the hazard ratio of a survival regression model

Tags: r, survival

I tried to get confident interval of hazard ratio in `survreg()` function, but it's not that straightforward as coxph.

```
Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(survival, DIED) ~ AGE + GENDER + PLATE + 
NEUTRO + NIH, data = IMRAWandIST, dist = "exponential")
           Value Std. Error     z         p
PLATE        0.00236   0.000367  6.42  1.39e-10
EUTRO      -0.02726   0.016695 -1.63  1.03e-01
```

Scale fixed at 1

Exponential distribution
Loglik(model)= -4628.6   Loglik(intercept only)= -4736.1
    Chisq= 215 on 5 degrees of freedom, p= 0 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 5 
n=917 (28 observations deleted due to missingness)

```
#estimate of beta
a <- c(coefficients(summary(fitexp)))

print(coef <- (a * -1 * 1 / 1)

#estimate of HR

print(HR <- exp(coef))
```

The result doesn't have CI, only standard deviation, so my question is how can I transform SE of AFT coefficient into PH coefficient then compute the CI of HR.

I'm kinda stuck here. Can someone help?

Comment: Some data to reproduce the example will be helpful

Comment: It works for me. library(survival); fitexp<- survreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ ecog.ps + rx, ovarian, dist='weibull',scale=1);a<-c(coefficients(summary(fitexp)));print(coef<-(a*-1*1/1));print(HR<-exp(coef))

Comment: The coefficients and std errors are in the "table"- component of the list returned by `summary`. It's pretty much exactly like the case with `coxph`. I have no idea what the expression `(a * -1 * 1 / 1)` is supposed to represent.

Comment: Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(survival, DIED) ~ AGE + GENDER + PLATE + 
    NEUTRO + NIH, data = IMRAWandIST, dist = "exponential")
               Value Std. Error     z         p
(Intercept)  9.61783   0.284733 33.78 4.09e-250
AGE         -0.03443   0.003855 -8.93  4.16e-19
Scale fixed at 1 

Exponential distribution
Loglik(model)= -4628.6   Loglik(intercept only)= -4736.1
 Chisq= 215 on 5 degrees of freedom, p= 0 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 5 
n=917 (28 observations deleted due to missingness)

Comment: the result looks something like this, only has standard deviation, not CI.